# How to compile gRPC Proto files for Node?

Tags: grpc, grpc-node

The [gRPC documentation](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/) describes how to use the `protoc` command line program to compile a `*.proto` file to a certain language for all languages [except for Node](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/node/).

There, it is only described (at the time of this writing) how to dynamically load and at runtime (behind the scenes) generate the JS code.

Is it possible to use the `protoc` program to compile proto files to JS directly, similar to other languages?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found how to do static code generation for Node [on this GitHub page](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/node/static_codegen).

Here's a copy of the example they provide:

```
npm install -g grpc-tools
grpc_tools_node_protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:../node/static_codegen/ --grpc_out=../node/static_codegen --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`which grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin` helloworld.proto
grpc_tools_node_protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:../node/static_codegen/route_guide/ --grpc_out=../node/static_codegen/route_guide/ --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`which grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin` route_guide.proto
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that in newer versions of TypeScript there is a conflict with protoc-gen-ts and to generate TypeScript code you need for now to downgrade your version of TypeScript to v4.3.4

https://github.com/thesayyn/protoc-gen-ts/issues/170